# Create New Post link not showing in magento

Tags: magento2

I am running magento on localhost and want to create new post. But new post link is not showing. Pages showing under Content > Pages. I can only create pages not posts. But according to [this article](https://magefan.com/blog/new-blog-post-in-magento-2/) i can create new post too.

Please let me know how to add new post.

[image: Snapshot of content section]

Comment: Its in **Content** section.. Not in Content > Pages

Comment: @Abhishek Panchal please check snapshot. Only pages text is showing. But post text is not showing.

Comment: Did you run `setup:upgrade` and `static-content:deploy` command?

Comment: @Abhishek Panchal i don't know how to run this comment. I need to run command using cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read this doc. it will help you to run command and give you clear understanding of what it does.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands.html

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: my XAMPP is installed in e so i am using this

   php E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento\bin\magento setup:upgrade

but showing this error

   'E:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\bin\magento' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: if you are already in `bin` folder then run `php magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: sorry did not get what you said

Comment: open your Command promt. Go to your project location `cd E:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\bin\`  After that run `php magento setup:upgrade` command